# erlang: automatically launch/stop applications for tests

Tags: erlang, eunit

have some function which performs html parsing of some content from web page.
I want to write some set of tests for it. In tests I'm going to fetch html content via `httpc:request` and pass it to my function with result validation in the end.  But http client required application `inets` to be launched. After reading some docs about EUnit I came up with next chunk of code:

```
-module(dparser_tests).
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

start() ->
  inets:start(),
  ok.

stop(_) ->
  inets:stop(),
  ok.

do_smth(_) ->
  [?_assert(true =:= true)].


do_some_test_() ->
  {"Performs some default parsing stuff!",
    {setup, 
      fun start/0,
      fun stop/1,
      fun do_smth/1
    }
  }.
```

then

```
erlc dparser_tests.erl && erl -noshell -pa -eval "eunit:test(dparser)" -s init stop
```

and output is

```
*** context setup failed ***
::undef


=======================================================
  Failed: 0.  Skipped: 0.  Passed: 0.
One or more tests were cancelled
```

**UPDATE**
problem was in typo in `inets:start()`

Comment: Sorry but what is the question?

Comment: Question was - why did setup function refuse to start `inets`. Resolution is quite dummy - my typo in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the `start()` function. Replace `intets` with `inets` and the error will go away.